# Calculated field in Google Sheets not working

Tags: google-sheets

I have a pivot table created in a Google Sheet that looks like this:

```
Desktop           | Mobile
Sessions | Trans. | Sessions | Trans. |
  250    |   34   |   150    |   25   |
 ....    |   ...  | ....     |   ...  |
```

It's basically some web stats grouped by Desktop vs Mobile. I'm trying to add a new column for each group that will calculate `Trans. / Sessions`

I tried adding a calculated field to the pivot table, but when I enter the formula it shows `Formula parse error`. The way I entered it is by adding the column name wrapped in single quotes:

```
='Trans.' / 'Sessions'
```

[Here is an example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1D2asQ6FWm1eWe37AWqir3MMej0eB53EB1GKEm14A-uU/edit?usp=sharing).

Comment: Calculated fields work fine in my pivot table. Perhaps you could share yours so that the problem can be reproduced?

Comment: Here's an example: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1D2asQ6FWm1eWe37AWqir3MMej0eB53EB1GKEm14A-uU/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears you were trying to enter 'SUM of Transations' and so on into the formula. But "SUM of" if not a part of the name, it's just an indication of how the column was summarized. The following works in the calculated formulas:

```
=Transactions/Sessions
```

Since those columns are summarized using SUM, you will get the sum of transactions divided by the sum of sessions.

Quotes are not necessary here since you don't have spaces in column names.